# how disable CORS in api getway GCP ? the target app is running in cloud run

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, cors, cloud, google-cloud-run

i have spring boot api running in cloud run, and i have an api getway to redirect front to this service cloud run.

I disable CORS in spring boot app, and when i deploy the front connected directly to back-end there is no problem, But when i put cloud run behind getway. there is CORS.

i have tried this config in my yaml file:

```
host: {getway}.cloud.goog
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: {getway}.cloud.goog
    allowCors: True
```

no success !

need help please,

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check this documentation on [enabling CORS support for Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/support-cors) wherein you need to include `swagger: "2.0"` and enclose the value of `host` and `name` in quotation marks?

Comment: Same thing, still CORS

Comment: CORS policy was previously available in the Cloud Run documentation but unfortunately it was previously deleted. You may file this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at it as it was available previously.